# volley send multiple image at same key

Tags: android, android-volley

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put("param", textcontent);
   return params;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
   Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<String, DataPart>();
   params.put("imgs", new DataPart(id + ".jpg", getFileDataFromBitmap(selectImg[0]), "image/jpeg"));
   return params;
}
```

i want send to server multiple images at same key 'imgs'
so, i try this code

```
   params.put("imgs", new DataPart(id + ".jpg", getFileDataFromBitmap(selectImg[0]), "image/jpeg"));
   params.put("imgs", new DataPart(id + ".jpg", getFileDataFromBitmap(selectImg[1]), "image/jpeg"));
   params.put("imgs", new DataPart(id + ".jpg", getFileDataFromBitmap(selectImg[2]), "image/jpeg"));
```

but, it's send image only last put..

so, how can i send images like this?

```
imgs.put(selectImg[0]);
imgs.put(selectImg[1]);
imgs.put(selectImg[2]);
params.put("imgs", imgs);
```

my multipartrequest Class code here. (after modify arraylist, error return type getByteData())

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    try {
        // populate text payload
        Map<String, String> params = getParams();
        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
        }

        // populate data byte payload
        Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
        if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
            dataParse(dos, data);
        }

        // close multipart form data after text and file data
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can't you create a `DataPart` array and put the array into the `params` map?

Comment: use arraylist try it, but error return type..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`HashMap` is collection of key, value pairs. In your case you are adding three different values with same key. Hence last added one overwrite previous values.

Create an `ArrayList` of values (in your case images) and use it as value for your key.

```
ArrayList<DataPart> dataPart = new ArrayList<>();

dataPart.add(DATA-PART-1);
dataPart.add(DATA-PART-2);
dataPart.add(DATA-PART-3);

Map<String, ArrayList<DataPart>> imageList = new HashMap<>();

imageList.put(KEY, dataPart);
```

Comment: return error..
before return type is datapart, but now arraylist,
so, multipartrequest class is error this code : Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();

Comment: @starnewnewstar3014 : had you find any solution for this issue?

if possible then provide source code or full content of file.

because I had face same problem.

Comment: did you get any solution